# how to make count in multiple selected student id

Tags: php

i have two tables, initial_vote and studinfo. on initial_vote table, it compose of userid and the choices1-4(studid), i store here the info where the selected student id's are not yet counted. in the studinfo table, this is where i want to have counting on the numvote column.

initial_vote table

```
     userid     choice1    choice2     choice3     choice4
     12345      c-1234     c-1134      c-1222      c-1345 
     23456      c-1674     c-1534      c-1342      c-1444
```

studinfo table

```
     studid     fname    lname     mname     numvote
     c-1234     maria    cruz      santos       
     c-1134     juan     santos    cris
     c-1222     borg     sample    bern
     c-1345     joy      girl      cute
```

i manage to get the studid of choices1-4 of user from the initial_vote shown like this

```
      $vote$_SESSION['userid'];
     function getinfo2($info2){
    global $voter; //lets say the userid here is 12345
    $info_select = "SELECT `$info2` FROM `initial_vote` WHERE `voter_studid`='".mysql_real_escape_string($voter)."'";
            if ($query_get = mysql_query($info_select)) { 
            if ($result = mysql_result($query_get, 0, $info2)) {
            return $result;
            }
            }
            }
     $c1 = getinfo2('choice1'); $c2 = getinfo2('choice2'); 
     $c3 = getinfo2('choice3'); $c4 = getinfo2('choice4');
```

but my problem now is, how could i add or make a function to count the selected studid's in the final_vote table(numvote column) as i click a submit button. i try my best but it didnt  work.

```
 if($_POST['submit']{
    // ????
 }else { echo "Not added"; }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You need to normalize your `initial_vote` table

Comment: @njk & thaJeztah.... thnks for responding